# How do I make when user type in text input then automatically it will convert to uppercase in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here an example my form http://jsfiddle.net/GT7fY/

How to convert all text to uppercase while user writing on the field?

Comment: Thank you guys. +1 for implementation & examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `keyup()` and `toUpperCase()`

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
   this.value = this.value.toUpperCase(); 
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/GT7fY/2/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
style input
input{text-transform:uppercase;}​

and onBlur make uppercase
<input onBlur="$(this).val(this.value.toUpperCase());">
```

That's it :)

Comment: But not what was asked, it'd have to be something like onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" in pure JS to make it most efficient....

Comment: @Likwid_T any way you should style it.

Answer (score 3):

I would just convert it to uppercase in the submit event.

```
$("#verify input").val(function(i,val){
  return val.toUpperCase();
});
```

The uppercase requirement could simply be kept hidden from the user.

Comment: I agree. If it's not important for the user to SEE that it's uppercase, just don't bother and carry on. Could even do the conversion on the back end instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('form#verify').on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Paste This at the bottom:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).val(this.value.toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(":input").keyup(function() {
$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

all yours.